# Route incoming traffic to pods with labels specified in URL

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, haproxy-ingress

I would like to use parameter passed in URL to route traffic to pods with specific labels. I can't tell in advance which values of `app` will be used, so it must somehow dynamically create Ingres rules/Services:

**Example:**

https://foo.bar.com/?app=application1 --> route to service/pods with `label: app=application1`

https://foo.bar.com/?app=application2 --> route to service/pods with `label: app=application2`

https://foo.bar.com/?app=non-existing-app --> route to service/pods without any label `app`.

I am wondering if it's possible using variables in `path` and corresponding services, here is the idea and pseudo-code:

```
kind: Ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app=${APPLICATION}
        backend:
          serviceName: app-${APPLICATION}
          servicePort: 8080
```